# #linkedin authentication not working - OAUTH2 APP AUTHORIZATION CODE REQUEST

Tags: linkedin-api

linkedin authentication is looping back and not allowing you to login via app - any ideas if something has changed as I get the following logged in the API in Linkedin but nothing else... OAUTH2 APP AUTHORIZATION CODE REQUEST

Answer (score 1):

Same here, this may be related to the changes they are applying to their API, [here](https://developer.linkedin.com/blog/posts/2015/developer-program-changes)